# Combine two words into one in C

Tags: c, string-concatenation

**Task**:

> Several lines are read from the input stream.
> The first line contains the number `N` - the number of remaining lines (tests), `N < 32`.
> Each of the next `N` lines contains two words separated by a space. (The length of each word does not exceed 32).
> It is necessary to get a new word for each pair of words, so that the ending of the first one coincides with the beginning of the second one, for example, `mountain` + `insane` = `mountainsane`. This word should be output to the standard output stream.
> If it is possible to connect words in several ways, you should choose the one that provides the maximum common part, e.g. `papa` + `papaha` = `papaha` (not `papapapaha`).
>
> **Note**: it is unacceptable to output the final string character by character using the `"%c"` format. It is necessary to form and output the whole string using the `"%s"` format.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int word_length(char *str)
{
    unsigned short int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char word_1[32], word_2[32], line[64][64];
    unsigned short int n, line_number, i, j, k;

    scanf("%hu", &n);

    for (line_number = 0; line_number < n; line_number++) {

        scanf("%s %s", word_1, word_2); 

        if (word_2[0] == word_1[0] && word_2[1] == word_1[1]) { 

            for (i = 0; i < word_length(word_2); i++) {
                line[line_number][i] = word_2[i];
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < word_length(word_1); j++) {
                if (word_2[0] != word_1[j]) {
                    line[line_number][j] = word_1[j];
                } else {
                    line[line_number][j] = word_2[j];
                    break;
                }
            }      
            for (k = j; k <= word_length(word_2); k++) {
                line[line_number][k] = word_2[k - 1];
            }   
        }  
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (line_number = 0; line_number < n; line_number++) {
        printf("%s\n", line[line_number]);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is to go by the first word and look for a match with the first letter of the second word. If the letters are different, then the letter from word 1 is written down, if they match, then all letters from word 2 are written down. However, I'm not sure if this logic is correct.

| Try | Expect | Got |
| --- | --- | --- |
| papa mama | papamama | papaa |
| mountain insane | mountainsane | mountae |
| play yoga | playoga | plaga |
| papa papaha | papaha | papaha |

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: Did you just copy your homework task?

Comment: Obviously the last character of the first word can always ruin everything: "word order" merges but "work order" does not.  What does that tell you about which characters to be examining?

Comment: Aside: `char word_1[32], word_2[32]` are both too short to store a string whose length is 32...

Comment: Why do you check `if(word_2[0] == word_1[0] && word_2[1] == word_1[1])` ?  Shouldn't you be checking the end of word 1 against the start of word 2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I came up with this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mergeWords(char* word1, char* word2) {
    int len1 = strlen(word1);
    int len2 = strlen(word2);
    int maxSize = len1 + len2 + 1;

    char* merged = (char*)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(char));
    int commonLen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        int match = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < len1 - i; j++) {
            if (word1[i + j] != word2[j]) {
                match = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) {
            commonLen = len1 - i;
            break;
        }
    }

    strncpy(merged, word1, len1 - commonLen);
    merged[len1 - commonLen] = '\0';
    strcat(merged, word2);

    return merged;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char word1[33], word2[33];
        scanf("%s %s", word1, word2);
        getchar();

        char* merged = mergeWords(word1, word2);
        printf("%s\n", merged);
        free(merged);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but many problems to fix: no explanation, dubious use of `strncpy`, incorrect index values in the inner loop causing invalid reads beyond the end of both strings. No protection against buffer overflow in `scanf("%s %s", word1, word2);`

Answer (score 3):

About the OP code:

1. Too much vertical space (with 2xSP indent) making it difficult to read.
2. Rewriting `strlen()` for no apparent reason. (`string.h` has been included.)
3. `char w1[32];` (and `w2`) doesn't account for trailing NUL.
4. `char line[64][64];` is wholly inappropriate.
5. No verification of return code from `scanf()`.
6. The loops appear to be only guesses at the solution.

There is no stipulation that all the lines must be buffered to be output before terminating. Each line can/should be output as it is formed from its two words.

---

Below is annotated code that works (using compiled "strings" rather than reading input from a file):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *combine( char *dest, char *w1, const char *w2 ) {
    /* omitting checks for NULL pointers for brevity */
    /* all string buffers presumed to be of sufficient size */
    strcpy( dest, w1 ); // "word1" is always present in output

    size_t len1 = strlen( w1 ); // get both lengths
    size_t len2 = strlen( w2 );

    // determine minimum of lengths
    size_t len = len1 < len2 ? len1 : len2;

    // point into destination at that negative offset from trailing end
    // this is the point of maximum possible "overlap"
    char *cp = dest + len1 - len;

    // loop attempting to match that many characters
    while( *cp ) {
        if( strncmp( cp, w2, len ) == 0 ) {
            // matched "suffix" with "prefix"!!
            strcpy( cp, w2 ); // overlay all of "word2"
            return dest; // all done
        }
        cp++; // shorten suffix being tested
        len--; // reduce length being compared
    }

    strcat( dest, w2 ); // no commonality, so concatenate
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char *tests[][3] = {
        { "papa", "mama", "papamama" }, // w1, w2 and expected result
        { "mountain", "insane", "mountainsane" },
        { "play", "yoga", "playoga" },
        { "papa", "papaha", "papaha" },

        { "", "foobar", "foobar" },
        { "foobar", "", "foobar" },

        { "foobarfoo", "bar", "foobarfoobar" },
    };
    size_t nTest = sizeof tests/sizeof tests[0];

    char dest[ 64 + 1 ]; // Account for trailing NUL

    for( size_t i = 0; i < nTest; i++ )
        printf( "'%s' + '%s'\n\t'%s'\n\t[%s]\n",
            tests[i][0], tests[i][1],
            combine( dest, tests[i][0], tests[i][1] ),
            tests[i][2] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
'papa' + 'mama'
        'papamama'
        [papamama]
'mountain' + 'insane'
        'mountainsane'
        [mountainsane]
'play' + 'yoga'
        'playoga'
        [playoga]
'papa' + 'papaha'
        'papaha'
        [papaha]
'' + 'foobar'
        'foobar'
        [foobar]
'foobar' + ''
        'foobar'
        [foobar]
'foobarfoo' + 'bar'
        'foobarfoobar'
        [foobarfoobar]
```

The crutch of the challenge is to recognise and start from "maximum possible overlap", and work from there...

---

**New day, code tweak:**
The function's `while()` loop can be shortened to simplify the code:

```
    // while not matching remaining characters
    while( *cp && strncmp( cp, w2, len ) ) {
        cp++; // shorten suffix being tested
        len--; // reduce length being compared
    }

    strcpy( cp, w2 ); // put w2 here
    return dest;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is 100% correct (and I am not sure about the task itself [the description is too brief and does not explain many corner cases]) and do not have too much time to check, but it works with your test cases.

1. Use functions.
2. Do not overcomplicate simple tasks.

```
char *combine(char *w1, const char *w2)
{
    char *dest = w1;
    while(*w1)
    {
        if(*w1 && *w2) 
        {
            if(*w1 == *w2) w2++;
        }
        if(*w1) w1++;
        if(!*w1) strcpy(w1, w2);
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){"papa"}, "mama"));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){"mountain"}, "insane"));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){"play"}, "yoga"));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){"papa"}, "papaha"));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){"papa"}, ""));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){""}, "papaha"));
    printf("`%s`\n", combine((char[100]){""}, ""));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xP1nsazMG

Output:

```
`papamama`
`mountainsane`
`playoga`
`papaha`
`papa`
`papaha`
``
```

Comment: Sorry. It may correctly solve the specific examples, but not the general case of the problem description...

Comment: @Fe2O3 how can you know? The task is very unclear. And also provide examples which do not work

Comment: "_...so that the ending of the first one coincides with the beginning of the second one_" Changed to "mouninstain" and this code produces "mouninstaine" which is obviously wrong... The task is not unclear...

Comment: Try "aperiodic" and "period"... "_so that the ending of the first one coincides_" This is not happening in this code...

Comment: `if(*w1 && *w2)` simplify-able to `if(*w2)` and `if(*w1) w1++;` --> `w1++;`.

Comment: I am afraid this is incorrect: `combine((char[100]){"ab"}, "a"))` produces `"ab"` instead of `"aba"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `word_length` is a bogus reimplementation of `strlen` that has an infinite loop on strings longer than `USHORT_MAX`. Why did you not use `strlen`?
- `char word_1[32], word_2[32]` defines arrays that are too short for words with a length of `32 characters, you need at least one extra element for the null terminator.
- `char line[64][64]` defines a 2D array which is not necessary for this program as you can output the combined word immediately after reading the words.  Furthermore the second dimension should be at least `65` to handle the concatenation of non overlapping words of 32 characters each (you need space for the null terminator), and the task specification says you have at most `32` test cases, hence the first dimension does not need to exceed `32`.
- you should test for `scanf()` failure to convert the input according to the format strings and exit the program.
- `scanf("%s %s", word_1, word_2);` does not protect against buffer overflow if the input contains words longer than 32 bytes.  Assuming the arrays are defined with a length of `33`, you should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination arrays this way:

  ```
   scanf("%32s %32s", word_1, word_2);
  ```
- the overlap detection loop is incorrect:

  - if the first 2 bytes are identical, you just copy `word_2` and omit the null terminator, so combining `"aa1"` and `"aa"` results in `"aa"` instead of `"aa1aa"`.
  - otherwise you copy all characters from `word_1` different from the first character of `word_2` and then attempt to copy the rest of `word_2` without further testing.  This is also incorrect as `"ba1"` and `"ab"` results in `"bab"` instead of `"ba1ab"`.

Here is a simple alternative with unit tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *catenate_no_overlap(char *dest, const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    if (!s1) s1 = "";
    if (!s2) s2 = "";
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    // determine the maximum overlap between the end of s1 and the beginning of s2
    size_t overlap = len1 < len2 ? len1 : len2;
    while (overlap > 0 && memcmp(s1 + len1 - overlap, s2, overlap))
        overlap--;
    // copy the bytes from s1
    memcpy(dest, s1, len1);
    // copy the non overlapping part of s2 and the null terminator
    memcpy(dest + len1, s2 + overlap, len2 - overlap + 1);
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
#ifdef TESTING
    const char *tests[][3] = {
        // tests from the OP question
        { "papa", "mama", "papamama" },
        { "mountain", "insane", "mountainsane" },
        { "play", "yoga", "playoga" },
        { "papa", "papaha", "papaha" },
        // tests for corner cases
        { "", "", "" },
        { "", "hello", "hello" },
        { "hello", "", "hello" },
        { "hello", "hello", "hello" },
        { NULL, NULL, "" },
        { NULL, "hello", "hello" },
        { "hello", NULL, "hello" },
        { "ababa", "babab", "ababab" },
    };
    int numTests = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]);
    int fails = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
        char buf[64 + 1];
        char *dest = catenate_no_overlap(buf, tests[i][0], tests[i][1]);
        if (strcmp(dest, tests[i][2])) {
            printf("test %d failed: \"%s\", \"%s\" -> \"%s\", expected \"%s\"\n",
                   i, tests[i][0], tests[i][1], dest, tests[i][2]);
            fails++;
        }
    }
    if (fails) {
        printf("Test failures: %d / %d\n", fail, numTests);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("All tests passed: %d / %d\n", numTests, numTests);
        return 0;
    }
#else
    char word_1[32 + 1], word_2[32 + 1], dest[64 + 1];
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (scanf("%32s %32s", word_1, word_2) != 2)
            return 1;
        printf("%s\n", catenate_no_overlap(dest, word_1, word_2));
    }
    return 0;
#endif
}
```